# facebook api date conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am making my first app in codeigniter that draws birthdays from the facebook api and places them into a mysql database.  The dates coming from the facebook api are 00-00-0000 and I need them to be converted to 0000-00-00.

I am using this bit of code to pull the data from facebook:

```
  try{
        $fql    =   "SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND strlen(birthday_date) > 0";
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}
```

I am using this bit of code to put the query from the api to mysql:

```
this->db->insert_batch('friends_birthdays', $fqlResult);
```

Do I need to escape the `$fqlresult` string first or is there something helpful in codeigniter that will help me do this?  Sorry if this sounds stupid but I am a noob and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) e.g.

```
<?php
  $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
  for($i=0;$i<count($fqlResult);$i++) {
      $fqlResult[$i]['birthday_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fqlResult[$i]['birthday_date']));
  }
  $this->db->insert_batch('friends_birthdays', $fqlResult);
?>
```

Comment: I am having trouble wrapping my head around the fact the the top piece of code gives my a variable of '$fqlresult' so how do I take that and pull individual variables from within that string.  Again sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Its funny you asked that.  I was just looking into it.  What do you think?    'array(7) { [0]=> array(3) { ["uid"]=> string(9) "614070563" ["name"]=> string(14) "Noah Jr" ["birthday_date"]=> string(10) "11/21/1966" } [1]=> array(3) { ["uid"]=> string(9) "630712701" ["name"]=> string(9) "Ana B" ["birthday_date"]=>'.. etc

Comment: I also tried: 'var_dump($array["birthday_date"]);' but it said it was an undefined index

Comment: it's a multidimentional array that is why you can't just do $array["birthday_date"]. You need to use a loop to change all values for a key.

Comment: Thanks you so much Ignas!!! you just saved me so much time. This works perfectly.

Comment: _Please_ get some basic PHP programing skills before continuing …